# Importação de modulos Python ImportError('cannot import name rr',))

Tags: python, json

Eu tenho dois códigos python, um que se chama [recebimento.py] outro que se chama [enviar.py] eu estou com um problema de importção dos meus códigos. 
Vou enviar só uma pequena parte do meu código que estou com problema.

EX:

**ENVIAR.py**

```
import pika
def envio(ch, method, properties, body):
     print(body)
     try:
         dados_envio = json.loads(body)
         from recebimento import run,rr
         run(data)
         rr(data) ## aqui é a conexão com meu codigo "recebimento.py" para ele receber dados do "enviar.py"
```

**RECEBIMENTO.py**

```
import json
def run(data):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('google.com')
    elemento = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    elemento.send_keys('{}'.format(data['nome']))
    def rr(data):
        elemento2 = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
        elemento2.clear()
        elemento2.send_keys('{}'.format(data['cidade']))
```

eu quero fazer troca de dados com mais de um função.

mas recebo esse erro.

```
ImportError('cannot import name rr',))
```

alguem sabe como me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na linha `from recebimento import run,rr` do arquivo `enviar.py`. Você está tentando importar do módulo a função `rr` que está dentro de uma outra função. Por isso está acontecendo este erro. Em Python, não é possível você utilizar variáveis, funções e outros, criados localmente ( criados dentro de funções, métodos, etc ).

Para resolver este problema, a função `rr` deve ser criada dentro do escopo `global`. Exemplo:

```
import json
def run(data):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('google.com')
    elemento = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    elemento.send_keys('{}'.format(data['nome']))
def rr(data):
    elemento2 = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    elemento2.clear()
    elemento2.send_keys('{}'.format(data['cidade']))
```

Talvez a troca de escopo da função não afete o seu programa. Fora isso, você pode também retornar essa função, passando ela para uma variável chamada `rr` no escopo global. Exemplo:

```
import json
def run(data):
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('google.com')
    elemento = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
    elemento.send_keys('{}'.format(data['nome']))
    def rr(data):
        elemento2 = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
        elemento2.clear()
        elemento2.send_keys('{}'.format(data['cidade']))
    return rr
rr = run(data)
```

Dessa forma a variável `rr` contendo a função será importada.